# Synaptics Touchpad Windows 7 Driver Continually Installs HID-Compliant instead of Proprietary

Tags: windows-7, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

**My Problem**

My Acer e5-521-66sn Synaptics Touchpad in Windows 7 uses no gestures and installs as a generic Windows mouse and not Synaptics brand.

I have recently undergone the extremely annoying destruction of Windows 8.1 on my new laptop I received for Christmas. I have re-installed a clean Windows 7 ISO and have managed to reverse look-up all hardware id's and vendor id's for MOST of my system. I am missing only a few now, one of which being the Synaptics touchpad that my laptop came with. When I first turned on the machine into Windows 8.1 and played with the mouse I noticed that it was setup (via Gestures) to act like a Mac mouse. I liked this functionality and thought to re-instate this behavior. However here lies the problem.

I must say that I have been at this all morning and last night and have scoured at least 100 or more forum posts on a variety of sites about this topic and it seems people either think that Windows 7 does not recognize this as a Touchpad and instead simply registers its driver as a default HID-Compliant generic Windows mouse. Or, they think that this is caused by accidentally turning off my mouse pad with fn+f7. This is not the case.

**Currently I Can...**

Use my Touchpad mouse like a normal Windows mouse. I can touch the pad to click however pushing the pad in (my pad has no buttons on it, pushing it in acts like a mouse click) is no longer working. None of the gestures are working and the only way to perform right click is to push the pad in while being very close to the edge of the bottom right hand side.

**Inside of Device Manager...**

This mouse pads Hardware and Vendor Id's are: Hardware: 06cb ; Vendor: 2970. It shows up as HID-compliant instead of Snyaptics branded. There are no services running in my task manager related to Synaptics, none in my resource manager, no programs installed under my programs list and lastly no Synaptics tab in the mouse properties window.

**I have tried...**

I have been to both third party sites (huge mistake but was desperate) and also going to the Synaptics driver page [here](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php#info_content). The official Synaptics page driver comes with many executables and I have tried them all. All of which end like with a successful screen like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcTQr.png).

I have tried removing the mouse, uninstalling the driver and deleting any mouse related services running from the computer which renders my Touchpad useless and unable to even move. If I wait even 5 minutes Windows auto-magically adds the driver by itself and makes it HID-compliant yet again.

I have tried turning off my machine, unplugging all devices, removing the battery, clearing cache by holding power for 15-30 secs then powering on. No effect.

I have tried using god-awdul third party driver updates and after I made that mistake I wiped my new Windows 7 install and HDD and started all over because I felt compromised via bloatware, malware and or generic viruses.

[This persons](https://superuser.com/questions/695072/synaptics-official-driver-package-successfully-installed-but-driver-not-loaded) post is the closest to my problem that I have found, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/695072/synaptics-official-driver-package-successfully-installed-but-driver-not-loaded).

Comment: You can give a try forcing the change of hid device driver. Select it in computer managment, click on change driver and manually find the synaptic driver. You have to checkmark "Show all devices" in driver window if the driver is not recognised as possible candidate for that device.

Comment: No dice same problem